# html login security problem

Tags: javascript, html

```
function LogIn() {
    loggedin = false;
    username = "";
    password = "";
    username = prompt("Username:", "");
    username = username.toLowerCase();
    password = prompt("Password:", "");
    password = password.toLowerCase();
    if (username == "user" && password == "123") {
        loggedin = true;
        window.location = "video embed.html";
    }
    if (loggedin == false) {
        alert("Invalid login!");
    }
}
```

Any body know how to hide this login password in to database access ? this html page is not published.

Comment: Please format your code correctly next time. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can't hide anything done in javascript from the user. You need to manage authentication on the server.

Comment: @trufa  i dont know how to format the text

Comment: I hope you're not getting paid for this. It would make me cry.

Comment: @peter im do this is not selling,just for my exercise base on the subject i taking now.

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly the most insecure way to implement authentication in a web application. All of this information will be sent across the wire in plaintext.

You're also always lowercasing the user's information so credentials are becoming even less secure.

The typical way to go about building out an authentication system would be:

- Create a form that accepts a username and password
- Verify the user information on the server-side by evaluating it against the information in the database table.
- Return a response to the client-side based on the success or failure of the credentials

All of this is contingent upon properly and securely registering a user.  To do this:

- Accept a username and password in a registration form
- Apply a hash and a salt to the specified password
- Serialize the information to the database

In all future logins attempts, you'll want to evaluate the users incoming information against the records stored in the database table by passing it through the same hash and salt.

The thing is, implementing something like this varies widely depending on the platform that you're using.

As far as evaluating this on the client side, the closest you'll be able to get to client-side validation is using Ajax to prevent a page refresh.

Comment: +1 But that's so much more complicated than just doing it the client!

Comment: Ah, true. Should I change up my answer? :)

Comment: now this page is not published, just i want to know got any method that can access login password on MS Access.

Comment: Yes. You should just tell him to obfuscate the string with the user name and password with some simple character replacement algorithm. ;)

Comment: @CKK999 you can't get server-side information on the client without actually running the request on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite general. There is no easy, short answer. First of all, you need a database in your server. Then you have to access it with some kind of script in the server (with PHP, ruby, or something like that). The last step would be send the user and password input to the server, check them there, and send back a response.

Try looking for a PHP tutorial on the net a read it. It should make your idea a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't verify the password on the client**, you need to check the password on the server. And then the resulting page must ensure that the password has already been checked. In other words, you can't rely on the fact that "no one knows the URL except my script" to secure the page.

There are plenty of ways to do this, in fact most web servers have a built-in way of securing URLs.

Comment: now this page is not published, just i want to know got any method that can access login password on MS Access.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with MS Access

Answer (score 0):

(If only to satisfy my inner pedant). It's not accurate to say you can't do any kind of password security without server side kit. It's quite doable to use use a JS SHA-1 implementation and store a (salted) hash of the password within the source code.

Admittedly it's not the ideal solution as shared pwds aren't so cool.

```
<html>
<script>

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  SHA-1 implementation in JavaScript | (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010 | www.movable-type.co.uk      */
/*   - see http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/secure_hashing.html                             */
/*         http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/examples.html                                   */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Sha1 = {};  // Sha1 namespace

/**
 * Generates SHA-1 hash of string
 *
 * @param {String} msg                String to be hashed
 * @param {Boolean} [utf8encode=true] Encode msg as UTF-8 before generating hash
 * @returns {String}                  Hash of msg as hex character string
 */
Sha1.hash = function(msg, utf8encode) {
  utf8encode =  (typeof utf8encode == 'undefined') ? true : utf8encode;

  // convert string to UTF-8, as SHA only deals with byte-streams
  if (utf8encode) msg = Utf8.encode(msg);

  // constants [§4.2.1]
  var K = [0x5a827999, 0x6ed9eba1, 0x8f1bbcdc, 0xca62c1d6];

  // PREPROCESSING 

  msg += String.fromCharCode(0x80);  // add trailing '1' bit (+ 0's padding) to string [§5.1.1]

  // convert string msg into 512-bit/16-integer blocks arrays of ints [§5.2.1]
  var l = msg.length/4 + 2;  // length (in 32-bit integers) of msg + ‘1’ + appended length
  var N = Math.ceil(l/16);   // number of 16-integer-blocks required to hold 'l' ints
  var M = new Array(N);

  for (var i=0; i<N; i++) {
    M[i] = new Array(16);
    for (var j=0; j<16; j++) {  // encode 4 chars per integer, big-endian encoding
      M[i][j] = (msg.charCodeAt(i*64+j*4)<<24) | (msg.charCodeAt(i*64+j*4+1)<<16) | 
        (msg.charCodeAt(i*64+j*4+2)<<8) | (msg.charCodeAt(i*64+j*4+3));
    } // note running off the end of msg is ok 'cos bitwise ops on NaN return 0
  }
  // add length (in bits) into final pair of 32-bit integers (big-endian) [§5.1.1]
  // note: most significant word would be (len-1)*8 >>> 32, but since JS converts
  // bitwise-op args to 32 bits, we need to simulate this by arithmetic operators
  M[N-1][14] = ((msg.length-1)*8) / Math.pow(2, 32); M[N-1][14] = Math.floor(M[N-1][14])
  M[N-1][15] = ((msg.length-1)*8) & 0xffffffff;

  // set initial hash value [§5.3.1]
  var H0 = 0x67452301;
  var H1 = 0xefcdab89;
  var H2 = 0x98badcfe;
  var H3 = 0x10325476;
  var H4 = 0xc3d2e1f0;

  // HASH COMPUTATION [§6.1.2]

  var W = new Array(80); var a, b, c, d, e;
  for (var i=0; i<N; i++) {

    // 1 - prepare message schedule 'W'
    for (var t=0;  t<16; t++) W[t] = M[i][t];
    for (var t=16; t<80; t++) W[t] = Sha1.ROTL(W[t-3] ^ W[t-8] ^ W[t-14] ^ W[t-16], 1);

    // 2 - initialise five working variables a, b, c, d, e with previous hash value
    a = H0; b = H1; c = H2; d = H3; e = H4;

    // 3 - main loop
    for (var t=0; t<80; t++) {
      var s = Math.floor(t/20); // seq for blocks of 'f' functions and 'K' constants
      var T = (Sha1.ROTL(a,5) + Sha1.f(s,b,c,d) + e + K[s] + W[t]) & 0xffffffff;
      e = d;
      d = c;
      c = Sha1.ROTL(b, 30);
      b = a;
      a = T;
    }

    // 4 - compute the new intermediate hash value
    H0 = (H0+a) & 0xffffffff;  // note 'addition modulo 2^32'
    H1 = (H1+b) & 0xffffffff; 
    H2 = (H2+c) & 0xffffffff; 
    H3 = (H3+d) & 0xffffffff; 
    H4 = (H4+e) & 0xffffffff;
  }

  return Sha1.toHexStr(H0) + Sha1.toHexStr(H1) + 
    Sha1.toHexStr(H2) + Sha1.toHexStr(H3) + Sha1.toHexStr(H4);
}

//
// function 'f' [§4.1.1]
//
Sha1.f = function(s, x, y, z)  {
  switch (s) {
  case 0: return (x & y) ^ (~x & z);           // Ch()
  case 1: return x ^ y ^ z;                    // Parity()
  case 2: return (x & y) ^ (x & z) ^ (y & z);  // Maj()
  case 3: return x ^ y ^ z;                    // Parity()
  }
}

//
// rotate left (circular left shift) value x by n positions [§3.2.5]
//
Sha1.ROTL = function(x, n) {
  return (x<<n) | (x>>>(32-n));
}

//
// hexadecimal representation of a number 
//   (note toString(16) is implementation-dependant, and  
//   in IE returns signed numbers when used on full words)
//
Sha1.toHexStr = function(n) {
  var s="", v;
  for (var i=7; i>=0; i--) { v = (n>>>(i*4)) & 0xf; s += v.toString(16); }
  return s;
}


/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
/*  Utf8 class: encode / decode between multi-byte Unicode characters and UTF-8 multiple          */
/*              single-byte character encoding (c) Chris Veness 2002-2010                         */
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

var Utf8 = {};  // Utf8 namespace

/**
 * Encode multi-byte Unicode string into utf-8 multiple single-byte characters 
 * (BMP / basic multilingual plane only)
 *
 * Chars in range U+0080 - U+07FF are encoded in 2 chars, U+0800 - U+FFFF in 3 chars
 *
 * @param {String} strUni Unicode string to be encoded as UTF-8
 * @returns {String} encoded string
 */
Utf8.encode = function(strUni) {
  // use regular expressions & String.replace callback function for better efficiency 
  // than procedural approaches
  var strUtf = strUni.replace(
      /[\u0080-\u07ff]/g,  // U+0080 - U+07FF => 2 bytes 110yyyyy, 10zzzzzz
      function(c) { 
        var cc = c.charCodeAt(0);
        return String.fromCharCode(0xc0 | cc>>6, 0x80 | cc&0x3f); }
    );
  strUtf = strUtf.replace(
      /[\u0800-\uffff]/g,  // U+0800 - U+FFFF => 3 bytes 1110xxxx, 10yyyyyy, 10zzzzzz
      function(c) { 
        var cc = c.charCodeAt(0); 
        return String.fromCharCode(0xe0 | cc>>12, 0x80 | cc>>6&0x3F, 0x80 | cc&0x3f); }
    );
  return strUtf;
}

/**
 * Decode utf-8 encoded string back into multi-byte Unicode characters
 *
 * @param {String} strUtf UTF-8 string to be decoded back to Unicode
 * @returns {String} decoded string
 */
Utf8.decode = function(strUtf) {
  // note: decode 3-byte chars first as decoded 2-byte strings could appear to be 3-byte char!
  var strUni = strUtf.replace(
      /[\u00e0-\u00ef][\u0080-\u00bf][\u0080-\u00bf]/g,  // 3-byte chars
      function(c) {  // (note parentheses for precence)
        var cc = ((c.charCodeAt(0)&0x0f)<<12) | ((c.charCodeAt(1)&0x3f)<<6) | ( 

c.charCodeAt(2)&0x3f); 
        return String.fromCharCode(cc); }
    );
  strUni = strUni.replace(
      /[\u00c0-\u00df][\u0080-\u00bf]/g,                 // 2-byte chars
      function(c) {  // (note parentheses for precence)
        var cc = (c.charCodeAt(0)&0x1f)<<6 | c.charCodeAt(1)&0x3f;
        return String.fromCharCode(cc); }
    );
  return strUni;
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

function LogIn() {
    loggedin = false;
    username = "";
    password = "";
    username = prompt("Username:", "");
    username = username;
    password = prompt("Password:", "");
    salt     = "jenny";
    password = Sha1.hash(salt + password);

    if (username == "user" && password == "8c84bbf4f643d6b8c4c188935eb1196d8cdcf10b") {
        loggedin = true;
    alert("valid login!")
        //window.location = "video embed.html";
    }
    if (loggedin == false) {
        alert("Invalid login!");
    }
}


</script>

<body onload="LogIn();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to encrypt the document with that a key derived from that password. And plain SHA-1 isn't good for this either since it's too fast. A Key Derivation Function such as PKDF2 should be used.

Comment: "You need to encrypt the document with that a key derived from that password." - huh? the password doesn't need to be decrypted, never mind the document. "And plain SHA-1 isn't good for this either since it's too fast." - faster than lightspeed? / an elk? "A Key Derivation Function such as PKDF2 should be used" - now I know i'm in trouble..

Comment: Anything that is done in your web browser, a user can crack. They may not be able to discover the password (since SHA-1 and other hash functions are, by definition, 1-way functions that are irreversible, they are NOT encryption) but they can just bypass it entirely and make it "look" like they know the correct passsword.

Comment: Security by obscurity = BAD idea, that includes the myth of something being secure just coz it's on a "secure" server. The main point of above is to demonstrate that there's more than one way to skin a cat. Above IS a secure way of storing the password. The target web resource is another matter entirely..

Comment: We are talking about client side security here. So verifying the password isn't enough, we need to prevent it being circumvented too. This can be prevented in a scheme similar to what's used in disk encryption software. You only send the secret data in encrypted form, and decrypt it using the password. The problem with plain SHA is that you can check millions of passwords per second, and thus can brute-force medium entropy passwords. If you slow down the hash(and use a salt) brute-force becomes much slower.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess the guy should buy a quantum encryption system and a good programmer, or distribute his saucy films using a shop. The alternative is for us to balance attack probability, avg time to crack & the value of what he's trying to protect..

Comment: @trickwallett is too difficult to understand in SHA-1 because i dint study this subject. But thk for ur above information